# GitHub Actions: How to let a local server pull the change automatically from remote branch

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions, git-pull, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have the followings.

1. Apache server hosted on centos
2. GitHub (GitHub Actions)
3. An web app hosted on the local apache server.

Every time I make a change to a local branch and push to remote `master` branch in GitHub, I have to ssh into the apache server and run `git pull origin master`. What is the best way and how to set up an automatic pull/deployment on the local server so that it will listen and pull the change automatically?

I have read about GitHub Actions self-hosted runner and ssh solution. but I am not sure how to achieve this in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub actions to do this by specifically using the action `SFTP-Deploy` which essentially copies your code from your GitHub repo and places it in your apache server directory.